# Use sparse image bundle instead of split and concat

Tags: macos, disk-utility

Is it possible to use sparse image bundles on the Mac in the same fashion as I would use files split with Terminal's `split` command?

If I show the package contents of the sparse image bundle in the Finder I see the following directory structure:

```
token
Info.plist
Info.bckup
bands
    |
    |-1
      2
      3
      .
      .
      .
      .
```

The folder `bands` contains files that are almost all 8MB in size.
What I would like to do is upload these separate 8MB files, download them later, and put them together again in the sparse image bundle.

Would I be able to access the files on the recompiled disk image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that, but you'll have to be careful to reassemble the bundle components properly or it won't work. I'd recommend using a segmented image instead; that way you get control of the size of the files it's broken into, and there's less complexity to reassembling it. Use something like this:

```
hdiutil segment -o segmentedImage.dmg -segmentSize 20m unsegmentedImage.dmg
```

This will create segmentedImage.dmg, segmentedImage.002.dmgpart, segmentedImage.003.dmgpart, etc. To reassemble, just put them all in the same folder (with the filenames intact), double-click segmentedImage.dmg, and it'll mount.